# Ajax постоянные обновления div

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, php7

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема. Пишу что-то на подобие чата. Нужно сделать обновления чата без перезагрузки страницы, начал мыслить в сторону Ajax.
Но тот в свою очередь, обновляет страницу всегда и бесконечное множество раз.
Хотелось бы что-бы обновление чата происходило только когда появится новое сообщение.[image: То самое обновление]

Использую VPS сервер на Apache, MYSLi базу и PHP 7.2

Сама функция:

```
    <script>
        function show()  
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'greetings.php',
                data: 'message=show_all',
                cache: false,  
                beforeSend: function() {
                $('.content').html('Получаем контент');
                },
                success: function(html){
                    $('.content').html(html);
                }  
            });  
        }  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    show();
    setInterval('show()',4000);
 }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал как-то так, надеюсь помогу тем у кого такой-же вопрос))

```
function show_all() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/scripts/functions.php',
    data: 'message=show_all',
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
      if (html != outpt) {
        window.html = html;
        $('.messages_block').html(html);  
      }
    }
  });
  var outpt = window.html;
}
```

Обновляем только тогда, когда пришли новые данные.

Answer (score 0):

А что Вы, собственно, ожидали? В коде ясно написано обновление после выполнения запроса.
Для исправления: делайте проверку - есть ли в пришедшем что-то новое и только тогда обновляйте.
Но для чата в наше время использовать цикл бесконечных запросов - моветон, ибо есть (веб)сокеты, долгие запросы на худой конец.

Comment: Я это и вижу. Мне интересно как это можно осуществить. Можете дать какой-то пример?